# Best books for mathematical statistics self-study?

Tags: self-learning, statistics, probability

I'm hoping to start a masters in mathematics in the fall, and am hoping to find a good book on mathematical statistics to study so that I'll be able to take graduate level mathematical statistics once I start my degree. For context, my undergrad was in music, and I'm in the midst of taking prerequisites to qualify for the masters program. I'm taking finals for Linear Algebra and Calc III, and after that I will be taking Differential Equations, Methods of Proof, Real Variables, and Abstract Algebra. Are there any books you recommend for self-study in mathematical statistics? (preferably not too expensive if possible -- trying to save for school) Thank you!

Comment: You might have more luck asking over on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or possibly https://math.stackexchange.com/. If you do so, please link the questions to each other (or delete the question here).

Comment: Will try those next. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Given you seem to have zero exposure to this material, I would just look for a reasonable undergrad text.

I would avoid classes "for business" or the like (although really they are way better than nothing!)

I would also be a little careful about asking for "mathematical statistics".  Some people may interpret that as asking for a hyper theoretical course.

[Edit:  I just checked your post on MSE and, as expected, one user has already commented in minutes, suggesting a very hard core already grad level stats book (Shao, Springer publ.) that emphasizes "measure-theoretic probability theory".  This is insane for a person with zero previous prob/stats experience and who is a music major looking for a reasonable math masters.  But it's par for the course on SE to see these kind of recommend a too-hard book and ignore progression in the learning process.  And ignore the student's particulars.]

You do want a standard middle of the road class that a math dept would teach.  It's fine if there is some calculus involved.  But you don't want something super theory heavy.  Not with what I read between the lines in your math background (not extensive) and ambitions (masters). Plus it's really beneficial to just get some insights in prob/stats, not just a blizzard of formulas.

A good general, low-cost, easy-to-self-study option is the Schaum's Outline:

[https://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-Probability-Statistics-4th/dp/007179557X/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007179557X)

It's calculus based, but very gentle.  Not encyclopedic, but covers the key areas.  And an omnibus can be daunting.  Better to make a first pass that is more prioritized.  And it is cheap.  And easy to read, has answer key, etc. (good option for self studiers.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check that out! It will definitely help. Thanks for thinking about the context of where I’m at and where I’m hoping to go as well — that’s very helpful. Just to clarify I have also taken an introduction to stats course so I’ve had a *little* experience in stats, but yes, not much.

Comment: *grad level stats book that is "method-theoretic" in emphasis* -- Did you mean "measure-theoretic"? That makes sense to me, but "method-theoretic" doesn't, although admittedly I know very little statistics.

Comment: Fixed (spaces...)

Comment: *as expected, one user has already commented* -- I wish there was a way to word and phrase search one's comments, as then I could provide many dozens of such examples where I point out (in my comments to other comments or answers) that some suggestion is clearly inappropriate given what the OP has said. "first year calculus" seems to get interpreted as "first year graduate student wanting background for diff. manifolds", "precalculus" gets interpreted as pretty much anything (unfamiliarity with the term not really an excuse with a few seconds google search), algebra student **(continued)**

Comment: who specifically says they're in (precollege) school and having difficulty with simultaneous linear equations is sent to college linear algebra texts, someone asking a basic question about continuity (phrased in such a way that it's clear the person is roughly 1st semester non-rigorous calculus level) is told about open sets and topological spaces (as if this is the final generalization anyway, which is isn't), etc. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963961/13130) might have generated inappropriate suggestions, but I think I jumped in and answered it before this happened.

Comment: Yeah, they do that all the time--you knew what I was talking about.  ;)  Great job on that question, by the way.  You are a classy guy.

Comment: Blake, it's not clear to me that you will ever ncounter something like Shao in your math masters.  For instance, maybe you're just going to have one/some courses in stats. And how applied or theoretical they will be. Not really clear to me what you're driving at. Pivoting from music to get a job, I think.   (I did know a church choir director and organ player who also taught high school math, parish school, so I think of him.) In any case, the Schaum's is cheap and will solidify your exposure to basic issues in probs/stats.  And is a good reference.  Most MS's won't expect much more.

Comment: Yes, I'm planning on teaching community college math, which is why I'm wanting to get the MS. The faculty advisor was thinking of putting me in statistics because, according to him, a lot of CC math teachers are expected to teach statistics. I don't mind that because I really love statistics and would love the opportunity to teach it!

Comment: Otherwise, the advisor wants me to be taking analysis and abstract algebra.

Comment: Will check out the Schaum's -- thanks again!

Comment: And @DaveLRenfro I have seen that a number of times as well. Much agreed that people need to think about who they're talking to. I saw a quite rigorous proof as the answer to a question from someone who I believe was taking college algebra. I answered something much more intuitive and accessible and I think they got more out of my answer than the other one.

Comment: @blakedylanmusic: Sometimes in a comment or an answer I'll go well beyond what I think the OP is ready for, but I'll say something like "for others who might be interested" or "if you continue further in mathematics" or "in a graduate level course", whatever seems appropriate for the context the OP has provided. At least I usually say this, although sometimes I assume this is evident (especially when it's "for others who might be interested"), and hopefully when I've assumed this, it is, and not like what is discussed [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/181016/49593).

Comment: Maybe we need to make a meta post about this lol

Comment: Might try engaging with Sue VanHattum (poster, this forum).  She has a masters and teaches at a juco.  It sounds like you're getting decent local advice also.  Good luck.  Wish you the best--think the kids will like you as a teach.

Comment: Thank you @guest — that is very kind :)

Comment: I skipped this question because statistics is not my focus. But it sounds like you've gotten good advice.